# sftp tab completion in Mac OSX (Lion)

Tags: osx-lion, sftp, readline, tab-completion

Has anybody found a way to enable tab completion when using sftp on the command line in OSX (Lion)?

Under Snow Leopard I installed yafc using MacPorts to use sftp with tab completion, but this does not seem to work either (yafc 1.1.1 i686-apple-darwin11.2.0 on OSX 10.7.2).

Any tips or alternatives to get tab completion/readline/libedit to work with any command line based sftp client is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem has been resolved in the latest MacPorts version of yafc, see [this ticket](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33413).